# Aplay audio open error:Device or resource busy

Tags: display, alsa, audio-recording

**System : Ubuntu 16.04**

**What I want to do on the command line:**

```
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
```

**Result :**

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Try :

```
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
Playing WAVE 'output.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/
robotik@robotik:~/Desktop$ sudo aplay output.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=PCH > aplay.tht
```